# Validation for NRIC

Tags: java

I try to do a validation for NRIC. It only valid when the first and last character are letter and the length of the NRIC is 9. For example, S1234567G.

It will pop out wrong format message when user enter the wrong format,for example, S123D and S12345678G. Here are my codes.

```
    boolean isLetter = true;
    } else if (nric.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter NRIC");
    } else if (isLetter == false) {
        for (int count = 0; count < nric.length(); count++) {
            char i = nric.charAt(count);
            if ((i != 9) && (!Character.isLetter(nric.charAt(0)))
                    && (!Character.isLetter(nric.length() - 1)))
                isLetter = false;
        }
        if (isLetter == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NRIC wrong format");
        }
```

This is not the whole code. I have other validation for other text fields also. I just separated out the NRIC portion since I knew there is some error here.

It will create a record in my database whatever I entered. It just will not show the error message even the format is wrong. Can somebody help me check? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that means any kind of upper case ASCII letter, not literally any of kind letter, such as  `த` which would pass `Character.isLetter`.

It's easiest then to use a regex like `[A-Z][0-9]{7}[A-Z]`

Comment: What is regex? Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @GabrielHeng `if( inputString.matches( "[A-Z][0-9]{7}[A-Z]") )` Regex is short hand for Regular Expression.

Comment: So can I explain in this way? The first [A-Z] determines whether the first character is alphabet or not. the [0-9] checks whether the following character is digits or not. and the {7} just like an array,which limits the numbers of character to 7 only. And the last [A-Z] same as just now, determine whether is alphabet or not. Is that correct?

Comment: @GabrielHeng yes, it means, one character between A-Z. Then seven characters between 0-9. And then one character between A-Z. So `A0000000A` is for example valid.

Comment: By the way, is there any other ways to do validation in java swing? I am currently using if,else if and else statement which made my codes very long because there are many text fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a regular expression with `matches`, e.g.

```
nric.matches("\\p{Alpha}.{7}\\p{Alpha}")
```

According to your examples however, it seems like you only want to consider strings valid that start with an upper case letter, followed by seven digits, ending in another upper case letter, in which case you would use

```
nric.matches("\\p{Upper}\\d{7}\\p{Upper}")
```

(Recall that in regular expressions `X{n}` means `X` repeated `n` times.)

Comment: So what am I supposed to write? I am quite new to IT field and I have not seen this before. Would you please give an example?

Comment: Well it's all basically all there: `nric.matches("\\p{Upper}\\d{7}\\p{Upper}")` should return your desired result.

Comment: Yeah it works now. So can I explain in this way? The \\p{Upper} checks for the first character whether is alphabet or not. If it is lowercase, it will convert to uppercase automatically. And for the \\d{7}, it checks for the number of the following characters whether is 7 or not. And the last \\p{Upper} is same as the first one. Is that correct?

Comment: @GabrielHeng no, `\\p{Upper}` is implicit way to write `[A-Z]`, same for `\\d`, which is implicit `[0-9]`